# Stop Script Outputting as plain text so that it runs as a Script in a set Div parent Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, encode, plaintext

I'm trying to output a script via a CMS (Webflow) but the system is outputting it as plain text, which stops it from correctly embedding & running.

So for example rather than getting:-

```
<div clss="embed"><script type="text/javascript">whatever</script></div>
```

The output comes out as the same in the inspector, but just plain text (not running script):-

```
<div clss="embed">"<script type="text/javascript">whatever</script>"</div>
```

So my question is whether there is a way to target a specific container div with class '.embed' **(in Javascript or jQuery)** to always ensure that any code in that class is always correctly outputted as a functioning script, rather than just printed on the screen as text?

Thanks

Glennyboy

**Example Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var uri = 'https://impgb.tradedoubler.com/imp?type(js)g(228862)a(28418)' + new String (Math.random()).substring (2, 11);
document.write('<sc'+'ript type="text/javascript" src="'+uri+'" charset=""></sc'+'ript>');
</script>
```

Outputs on the page the same except in speech marks in the code " "

Comment: It sounds like the content of the element has been HTML encoded, which means this would be an issue with how the data is saved/retrieved.

Comment: Like Rory said, look into the database on how it's saved. < and > are probably saved as &lt; and &gt;. If that's the case, you'll need to either change the way the data is saved in the database (but this could lead to script injection) or change the way it gets output.

Comment: So is it the quotes that are causing a problem?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do, and the way you want to do it, is NOT possible. You cannot have a div or container to ALWAYS have FUNCTIONING javascript. The key here is FUNCTIONING. Based on what you are describing, the script you are trying to execute is probably escaped, and so it is not valid javascript.

To really achieve what you are trying to do (which, I assume, is to execute your script dynamically), you need to look at where you are getting that script from. It seems like the source you are using is escaping the javsacript. You will need to un-escape it, and then put it in a script tag dynamically.

Perhaps you could show a little more of your code, so we can see where you are getting the script from. We can probably make a suggestion as to how to properly un-escape it.

Comment: The codes are all affiliate links and I also originally thought it was escaping, but on inspection the code is intact, but just outputting as raw text

Comment: I'm actually getting a 404 from that url. Are you sure that's not what's happening?